# Get word at position in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

From a linter provider, I receive a [Point compatible array](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.4.0/Point)(line, column) where the error occured. Now I would like to hightlight the word surrounding that point, basically the result one would get if that exact point was double-clicked in the editor. Something like

```
const range = textEditor.getWordAtPosition(point)
```

Is what I hoped for, but couldn't find in the documentation.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for a while, there seems to be no API method for the given need. I ended up writing a small helper function based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174867/6213343):

```
function getWordAtPosition(line, pos) {
    // Perform type conversions.
    line = String(line);
    pos = Number(pos) >>> 0;

    // Search for the word's beginning and end.
    const left = Math.max.apply(null, [/\((?=[^(]*$)/,/\)(?=[^)]*$)/, /\,(?=[^,]*$)/, /\[(?=[^[]*$)/, /\](?=[^]]*$)/, /\;(?=[^;]*$)/, /\.(?=[^.]*$)/, /\s(?=[^\s]*$)/].map(x => line.slice(0, pos).search(x))) + 1
    let right = line.slice(pos).search(/\s|\(|\)|\,|\.|\[|\]|\;/)

    // The last word in the string is a special case.
    if (right < 0) {
        right = line.length - 1
    }

    // Return the word, using the located bounds to extract it from the string.
    return str.slice(left, right + pos)
}
```

Here, the beginning of the word is determined by the latest occurance of one of the characters (),.[]; or a blank.

The end of the word is determined by the same characters, however here the first occurance is taken as a delimeter.

Given the original context, the function can the be called using the API method [::lineTextForBufferRow](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.24.0/TextEditor#instance-lineTextForBufferRow) and the desired postion (column) as follows:

```js
const range = getWordAtPosition(textEditor.lineTextForBufferRow(bufferRow), 10)
```