# How can I highlight the inner text of an HTML article element by index with just vainilla js?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have an HTML document with the following `body`:

```html
<style>
  .highlighted {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>

<article>My text in an element</article>
```

I have the challenge to style the `i` letter from the `in` word inside the `<article>` tag with javascript, and I'm required to do it by it's `index` [8].
So far I can only think of starting with this...

```html
<script>
  const article = document.querySelector('article').innerText
  console.log(article[8]);
</script>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<article>My text <span class="highlighted">i</span>n an element</article>

// Console
>>>> "i"
```

...although I've never tried anything like this before, so I'm kinda lost with the following steps.

I supose I need to insert a `<span>` tag by this index, but I'm not sure how I would set the closing `</span>` tag or update the DOM.

**What would be a good way to achieve this kind of styling?**

Comment: What sort of "styling" result are you expecting? [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473451/6243352) shows how to figure out which word is under the cursor, then you can wrap it in a `<span>` or whatever you like.

Comment: Any kind of highlighting, making both the text red and the text's background yellow is preferable.

Comment: OK, please show what that would look like in HTML and CSS.

Comment: What do you mean with "its index"? articleElement.textContent[8] is just the letter "i", there is nothing to style because it's plain text. If you need things styled, you're going to have to take the text, _chop it up_ into three strings (before your string, your string, and after your string) and then replace your string with a HTML element like a `<span>` that you can then assign a class to (or set `style` values on, but don't do that: use classes).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! The word `in` would start by the [8] index, I supose I need to insert a `<span>` tag by this index, but I'm not sure how I would set the closing `</span>` tag or update the DOM. I've edited the question trying to clarify for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//get text of article
const article = document.querySelector('article').innerText;

//find index of word 'in'
const index = article.indexOf('in');

//opening and closing tags
const openingTag = '<span style="color:red">'
const closingTag = '</span>'

//insert tags into article
const newHTML 
  = article.slice(0, index) 
  + openingTag + 'in' + closingTag 
  + article.slice(index + 2);
document.querySelector('article').innerHTML = newHTML;
```

This code styles the first occurrence of the word "in" by setting the text color to red. If you want to do something else, change the `style` attribute of the opening tag.

`article.slice(0, index)` returns everything before the word "in." In your example, this would evaluate to `'My text '`. `article.slice(index + 2)` returns everything after the word "in" because "in" is 2 letters long. In your example, this would evaluated to `' an element'`. When all the strings are concatenated together, the result is `'My text <span style="color:red">in</span> an element'`.

Comment: Thank you so much for reviewing! This definitely looks like the answer I'm looking for. I'll strongly consider marking as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const HIGHLIGHT_IDX = 8;
const article = document.querySelector('article').innerText;
const words = article.split(' ');
let highlightCheck = words[0].length;
let wordToHighlight = words[0].length >= HIGHLIGHT_IDX && '0';
let wordIdx = 1;

while (!wordToHighlight) {
  highlightCheck += 1 + words[wordIdx].length;
  if (highlightCheck >= HIGHLIGHT_IDX) {
    wordToHighlight = wordIdx;
  } else {
    wordIdx += 1;
  }
}

words[wordToHighlight] =
  `<span class="highlight">${words[wordToHighlight]}</span>`;

document.querySelector('article').innerText = words.join(' ');
```