# Find position of the next word at position JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, indexof, hebrew

I have a string of Hebrew words like this :

> כלל הנה השמים מספרים כבוד אל. הנה תחלה

and an array of match indexes in this string. I need to find the position of the word after the word at a given position in the array. I also need for dots, commas and other such characters to not be included.

These reasons prevent me from using the code of [finding the word at a position in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173316/finding-the-word-at-a-position-in-javascript)

Edit :

The goal was to modify the function of this post to obtain the position of the word next to the position in parameter

Here is my solution finally :

```js
String.prototype.indexOfEnd = function(string, position) {
    var io = this.indexOf(string, position);
    return  (io == -1 ? -1 : io + string.length);
}

function getWordAt (str, pos) {

    str = String(str);
    pos = Number(pos) >>> 0;

    var left = str.slice(0, pos).search(/[\u0590-\u05fe]+$/),
        right = str.slice(pos).search(/[\s,.\t-_()]+/);

    if (right < 0) {
        return str.slice(left);
    }

    return str.slice(left, right + pos);
}


function getNextWordAt (str, pos) {
    var result = getWordAt(str, pos);
    for(let i=0; i<str.length - pos; i++) {
      let tempWord = getWordAt(str, pos + i)
      if (result != tempWord && tempWord != ' ' && tempWord != ',' && tempWord != '.' && tempWord != '') {
        return [phrase.indexOfEnd(tempWord, pos), tempWord];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your post with your current source code and data structures? That is, show your array and source string as code, not as block text. And also include any attempts you have tried.

Comment: So, what is the input? Please share the code that fails to clarify what you've got and an example output you want to get. Also, please let know if you consider the latest ECMAScript 2018+ regex solution, or if you plan to support some legacy browsers/JS environments.

Answer (score 1):

The code of the post you don't want to use is quite correct. But the basic regex isn't made for Hebrew. So you have to customise the "no whitespace" which is `/S` to the charcode range you need. A quick research brought this result for the charrange you of Hebrew you have to use in your regex: `\u0590-\u05fe`

You can extend the `\s` with any seperating char you want (e.g. `[\s,.\t]+`) for whitespaces, kommas, dots and tabs.

Editing the code of [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173316/finding-the-word-at-a-position-in-javascript) brought me to the following solution code for you (note that you have to read the text in Hebrew backwards):

```
function getWordAt (str, pos) {

    // Perform type conversions.
    str = String(str);
    pos = Number(pos) >>> 0;

    // Search for the word's beginning and end.


    nextWhitespace = pos + str.slice(pos).search(/\s/);
    str = str.slice(nextWhitespace+1);

    var left = str.slice(0, pos + 1).search(/[\u0590-\u05fe]+$/),
        right = str.slice(pos).search(/[\s,.\t]+/);

    // The last word in the string is a special case.
    if (right < 0) {
        return str.slice(left);
    }

    // Return the word, using the located bounds to extract it from the string.
    return str.slice(left, right + pos);

}
```

**Edit:** Added the following lines to the code to get the **NEXT** word:

```
nextWhitespace = pos + str.slice(pos).search(/\s/);
str = str.slice(nextWhitespace+1);
```

Comment: *This function accepts any whitespace character as a word separator, including spaces, tabs, and newlines*. OP mentions that there might be more than whitespaces between words.

Comment: true, i changed that :)

Comment: This code looks very good! but I also can't change it so that it returns the next word, do you have idea for this? Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMsika If you showed *your* code, you would have got an answer some n hours ago. We do not know what you have and what you expect. Thus, only you yourself can solve the issue.

Comment: @DanielMsika I didn't have the time to answer you earlier. It is actually really simple, I just get he next whitespace from the position and cut the string there. Getting the "left" variable wouldn't even be needed anymore but i left it there. Actually this code has a problem with the last word. It cuts it if the index is inside the last word. Let me know if that is a problem for you :)